# Read multiple XML files in BIRT

Tags: javascript, birt

I would like to read multiple XML files in iHUB 16 BIRT, as a scripted data source and not using in built XML Data Source Capability.
Example:  Input from path

```
Q1_2015_Salesperson_1.xml
Q2_2015_Salesperson_1.xml
Q3_2015_Salesperson_1.xml
Q4_2015_Salesperson_1.xml

Q1_2015_Salesperson_2.xml
Q2_2015_Salesperson_2.xml
Q3_2015_Salesperson_2.xml
Q4_2015_Salesperson_2.xml
so on ....
```

Each XML might have different tags or structure.

Comment: Can you provide information on what you've already tried, and what specific question you want to be answered?

Comment: i am new to BIRT and when i use an XML Data Source and provide the following code it works fine, as i am creating the dataset from the XML data source however this will static and will not work for a new XML schema.var DS = reportContext.getDesignHandle().getElementFactory().newOdaDataSource("Test", "org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml");
DS.setProperty("FILELIST", "archive/Q2_2016_Salesperson_1.xml");
reportContext.getDesignHandle().getDataSources().add(DS);


var DataSet = reportContext.getDesignHandle().getElementByID(5);
DataSet.setDataSource( DS.getName());